# TypeError: Cannot read property 'byteLength' of undefined with nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase

> I am not able to understand why firebase is not accepting the image, the following message is appearing: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'byteLength' of undefined**

I tried to add the 'byteLength' value to my object(req.file) but the same error continued.

Just below is my implementation

```
const firebase2 = require('firebase/app');
require('firebase/storage');


router.put('/addimage', multer.single('picture'), async (req, res, next) => {
   const newName = uuidv1() + "-" + req.file.originalname;
   var storageRef = firebase2.storage().ref('photo/'+ newName);
   storageRef.put(req.file);  
});
```

[image]

**This html example I did work. I am wanting to make a backend so I am migrating to nodejs**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Teste</title>
    <style>
        body {
            display: flex;
            min-height: 100vh;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        #uploader {
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;
            width: 50%;
            margin-bottom: 10%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <progress value="0" max="100" id="uploader">0%</progress>
    <input type="file" value="upload" id="fileButton"></input>

    <script src="https://gstatic.com/firebasejs/live/3.0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Your web app's Firebase configuration
        // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
        var firebaseConfig = {
          apiKey: "xxxxx",
          authDomain: "xxxxx",
          projectId: "xxxxx",
          storageBucket: "xxxxxxx",
          messagingSenderId: "xxxxxx",
          appId: "xxxxxxx",
          measurementId: "xxxxxx"
        };
        // Initialize Firebase
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

        var uploader = document.getElementById('uploader');
        var fileButton = document.getElementById('fileButton');

        fileButton.addEventListener('change', function(e){

            var file = e.target.files[0];

            var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('sweet_fifs/'+ file.name);

            var task = storageRef.put(file);

            task.on('state_changed', 
                function progress(snapshot) {
                    var percetage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                    uploader.value = percetage;
                },
                function error(err) {

                }
            )

        });
        
      </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Where is your `router` running? In a Google cloud function, Firebase cloud function or your own NodeJS install?

Comment: The images I am putting on firebase my application is on heroku

Answer (score 2):

The [`Reference#put`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#put) method expects a `Blob | Uint8Array | ArrayBuffer` as it's first argument. The `req.file` object you provide is none of these. However, we can see that there is a `Buffer` object available as a property of the `req.file` object and the same can be said of the content's type in that buffer. So all we need to do is pull out those values and pass them to `Reference#put()`. Also don't forget to create a response for the user and handle any errors.

```
router.put('/addimage', multer.single('picture'), async (req, res, next) => {
   const newName = uuidv1() + "-" + req.file.originalname;
   const storageRef = firebase2.storage().ref('photo/'+ newName);
   
   storageRef.put(req.file.buffer, {
     contentType: req.file.mimetype
   })
   .then(() => storageRef.getDownloadURL()) // after upload, obtain the download URL
   .then(
     (url) => {
       // persisted to storage successfully and obtained download URL
       res
         .status(201)
         .set("Content-Location", url) // use "Location" if you want to redirect to it
         .json({
           "message": "Upload successful"
         });
     },
     (err) => {
       // failed to save to storage
       logger.error({
         message: "Upload failed with error",
         errorMessage: err.message,
         errorStack: err.stack
       });

       res
         .status(500)
         .json({
           "message": "Upload failed",
           "error": err.code || "unknown"
         });
     }
   )
   .catch((err) => {
     // if here, something has gone wrong while sending back the response
     // likely a syntax error, or sending responses multiple times
     logger.error({
       message: "Unexpected rejection during /addImage",
       errorMessage: err.message,
       errorStack: err.stack
     });
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I was very happy. When trying to apply the solution you commented, it generated another error, as shown in the image below.

Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
C:\workspace\Job4You\node_modules\@firebase\storage\dist\index.cjs.js:515
        this.xhr_ = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        ^

ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined
    at new NetworkXhrIo

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to mention that `firebase/storage` is a browser-only part of the SDK. If you want to access Cloud Storage from Node, you should use [`firebase-admin`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start) to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I don't understand and I don't even know how to use firebase-admin, I will continue researching as you do.

Comment: @Sandro `firebase-admin` is a version of the `firebase` SDK designed to run on servers rather than browsers. For the most calls, you use it the same way you do `firebase` - just swap `firebase` for `admin` when importing using `import * as admin from "firebase-admin"`. Check out the [setup instructions here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).

Comment: thank you so much. Do you have an example to upload this image? I couldn't do or understand how you do it using this firebase-admin. Remembering that I'm doing the backend in nodejs for my college and I'm not using a screen to get the file, I'm using it via postman(rest)

Answer (score 2):

There are two reasons this could be happening one,

Happens when the **buffers** haven't been defined in the middleware. Since in your sample code I don't see the middleware I cannot assume, so here is how it should be.

```
const multer = require('multer')

//storage middleware
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
      
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

The second reason is the way you are accessing Firebase.A better way to do it is

```
const { initializeApp } = require("firebase/app"); 
const{ref,getDownloadURL,uploadBytesResumable}=
require('firebase/storage');
const { firebaseConfig, storage } = require('../firebase');
// Initialize a firebase application
initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Then access everything:

```
const time = Date.now();
const file = req.file;

//const firebaseFilePath = `images/${time + file.filename}`;
const storageRef = ref(storage, `images/${time + file.filename}`);

const metadata = {
 contentType: req.file.mimetype,
};

// Upload the file in the bucket storage
console.log('Array:', req.file.buffer);

const snapshot = await uploadBytesResumable(
  storageRef,
  req.file.buffer,
  metadata
);

// Grab the public url
const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref);
```

Here is the file that i have imported:

```
const { initializeApp } = require("firebase/app");
const { getStorage } = require('firebase/storage');

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: ***,
  authDomain: ***,
  projectId: ***,
  storageBucket: ***,
  messagingSenderId: ***,
  appId: ***,
  measurementId: ***
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const storage = getStorage(app);

module.exports = { firebaseConfig, storage };
```